# The state field path cannot be resolved to a collection type

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

In my Entity Modell I have a ManyToMany Relation between `User` and `UserGroup`
User is a common `@Entity` class, whereas `UserGroup` is an Java `enum`.

The mapping look like that:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = my.package.UserRight.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)    
@CollectionTable(name = "MD_USER_RIGHTS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "REF_USER_ID"))
@Column(name = "USER_GROUP")
@Getter @Setter private Set<UserRight> userGroups;
```

Everything works fine with that unless I try to access the userGroups set via JPQL. I do not want to expose all information from the User Entity to the next layer, so I wrote a simple JPQL Query to create some DTOs from my User Entity:

Simplified:

```
public List<UserDTO> findAllActive() {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW my.package.UserDTO(m.name, m.id, m.userGroups) 
                              FROM User m ");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT NEW my.package.UserDTO(m.name, m.id, m.userGroups) FROM User m]. 
[83, 95] The state field path 'm.userGroups' cannot be resolved to a collection type.
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JPQL syntax is well enough defined for constructor expressions by this

```
constructor_item ::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression | identification_variable
```

You cannot have a multi-valued path expression (a collection) as an input arg to a constructor in JPQL. 
No idea what that EclipseLink message is trying to say, mind

Comment: I Understand ... but do you also have a suggestion how I may get the desired outcome? Should be done in one query, not N+1

Comment: clearly you could do a query with a JOIN to the element, and return that data (single SQL), and reform the collection in your own code. Not perfect but would work